# Aggregate value under different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I want to get some aggregate values for a table for some different types of jobs. Can I combine these 3 queries into a single query?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS totaljobs,
    SUM(filesize) AS totalfilesize
FROM Job

SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS assignedjobs,
    SUM(filesize) AS assignedjobs
FROM Job
JOIN Assignment ON Assignment.job_id = Job.id

SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS unassignedjobs,
    SUM(filesize) AS unassignedjobs
FROM Job
LEFT JOIN Assignment ON Assignment.job_id = Job.id
WHERE Assignment.job_id IS NULL
```

The queries behave as you would expect, e.g. `totaljobs = assignedjobs + unassignedjobs`. I feel like there is way to do it more efficiently in one query but I don't know how.

Comment: Does `Assignment.job_id` contain only unique values? For if it doesn't, the first query's result cannot be the sum of results of the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    SUM(case when Assignment.job_id IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) AS assignedjobs,
    SUM(case when Assignment.job_id IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) AS unassignedjobs,
    COUNT(*) as totaljobs
FROM Job
LEFT JOIN Assignment ON Assignment.job_id = Job.id
```